# convert millisecond date to timestamp in php

Tags: php, timestamp

I'm using API that return date like `2018-04-19 20:32:51.439702` and timestamp like `1524153770.26`.

In PHP how to convert date like `2018-04-19 20:32:51.439702` to this timetamp like that?

Answer (score 4):

Convert the string to a [`DateTime`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) object and you can format the parts using the date format strings.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

for example:

```
echo (new \DateTime("2018-04-19 20:32:51.439702"))->format("U.u");
```

output:

```
1524169971.439702
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the seconds are always followed by 6 digits and you wish for a timestamp with only two decimal points then you can do something like this:

```
$date = "2018-04-19 20:32:51.439702";
echo strtotime(explode('.', $date)[0]).'.'.explode('.', (explode('.', $date)[1]/10000))[0];
```

In the "US/Pacific" timezone, this produces:

```
1524195171.43
```

---

If you want `1524195171.439702` then use this:

```
$date = "2018-04-19 20:32:51.439702";
echo strtotime(explode('.', $date)[0]).'.'.explode('.', $date)[1];
```